# Can't make pyramid of numbers

Tags: javascript

I Need to get this output:

```
1

2  3

4  5  6

7  8  9  10

11 12 13 14 15
```

What I've tried so far:

```js
function getPyramid() {
  let nums = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
    for (let n = 1; n < i; n++) {
      console.log(n);

    }
    console.log('<br/>');

  }
  return nums;
}
getPyramid();
```

Comment: A few steps you'll need to take: 1) You're never mutating `nums`. If you want to return it, you'll need to do so. 2) You'll need to add some logic for how many numbers are on each line. 3) You'll need to decide whether you're printing to the console (where you would use line breaks) or using HTML (where you would us a `br` tag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do with one single loop

```js
function getPyramid() {
  
let nums = 0;
let count = 1; 
let numbers = ''
  for (let i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
if(count === nums){
     count++
     nums = 0;
     console.log(numbers)
     numbers = ''
 }
 nums ++
 numbers += ' ' + (i +1) 
  }

}
getPyramid();
```

Or like this you can specify amount of rows..

```js
function getPyramid(rows) {
  
let nums = 0;
let count = 1; 
let numbers = ''
let i = 1
  while (count < rows + 1 ) {
if(count === nums){
     count++
     nums = 0;
     console.log(numbers)
     numbers = ''
 }
 nums ++
 numbers += ' ' + i
 i++;
  }

}
getPyramid(5);
```

Comment: I need get it in console. Without html

Comment: thanks, but on output we can see no space between numbers and just only numbers from 0 to 10 are displayed

Comment: So now the number 15 is visible..

Answer (score 0):

Apart from notes given by [jnpdx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560942/jnpdx) in the comments, I'd add some:

- for better convention between programmers we tend to name varible nested in for-loop: `i, j`
- `<br/>` for `HTML` new line, In JS we do `\n` for that!
- `number++` is same `number += 1`
- [Conditional_Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) `(expression)?true:false` instead of `if/else`

  ```js
  function getPyramid(Lines) {
  let number = 1; // the counter to display on each line of pyramid!
  for (let i = 1; i <= Lines; i++) {
      let str = '';//line to display
      for (let j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
         str += number++;//incrementing counter
         str += j!=i ? ' ' : ''; //to make space, but not at the end of line.
      }
     console.log(str);//display that line
  }
  }
  getPyramid(5);
  ```

Comment: Nice, but very hard for me as for beginner. Coulld you please to simplify your code?

Comment: I've added some explanation and comments in code to clarify it more, hope it helped, Happy coding ;)

Answer (score 0):

```js
    for (let i = 1 ; i <= 5; i++)
    {
      let s = []
      for (let x = i * (i - 1) / 2 + 1; x <= i * (i + 1) / 2; x++)
      { 
        s.push(x)
      }
      console.log(s.join(" "))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A completely unnecessary attempt to do this in a functional style:

```js
const ranged_array = (from, to) =>
  Array.from({ length: to - from + 1 }, (_, i) => i + from);

const pyramid = (lines) =>
  ranged_array(1, lines)
    .reduce((a, v, i) => {
      const prev = a[i - 1];
      const last_num = prev && prev[prev.length - 1] || 0;
      a.push(ranged_array(last_num + 1, last_num + v));
      return a;
    }, [])
    .map((v) => v.join(' '))
    .join("\n");

console.log(pyramid(5));
```